# Google Sheet Tab Change Notification

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, notifications

How can I get an email when a specific tab has a row added? How can I add more than one email address to be notified of the change to a the tab?

I need a Google App Script to notify me and specific others in my workplace by email when there has been a change to a specific tab in a Google sheet. Notification rules is too broad and triggers for any change to the whole workbook.

I tried an App Script, but it is still sending emails for changes to any tab in the entire workbook...not the specific tab.

Answer (score 2):

You can use an [installable on change trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#change) and check if the event type is `INSERT_ROW`. Although it doesn't mention it on that page (but it's mentioned [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36761853#comment13)), the event object also includes its source, so you can use it to get the name of the modified sheet:

```
function newRowAdded(event) {
  const monitoredSheetName = 'Clients';
  const emailAddresses = ['email1@example.com', 'email2@example.com'];

  if (event.changeType === 'INSERT_ROW' && 
      event.source.getActiveSheet().getName() === monitoredSheetName) 
  {
    MailApp.sendEmail(
      emailAddresses.join(','), 
      'New row added!', 
      'A new row has been added to sheet ' + monitoredSheetName
    );
  }
}
```